# Howto export customer for excel?

Tags: export, ce-1.4.0.1, cvs

I need to export customers into a excel format cvs would be ok.

I tried `System > Export/Import > Profiles` but this does not work as the [documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles) explains: `http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles`.

Note: I don't need to import this data back into Magento.

What's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Manage Customer >> Customers >> Click on that.

Then it will open a grid for customer

Then search Export to CSV. Select CSV and Press Export Button.

Comment: Thanks, that was simple! But I needed to import the csv into excel instead of open it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution with customer address in a small script

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach($collection as $customer) {
    $customerAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
    if ($customerAddressId){
        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customerAddressId);

        $fields = array(
            $customer->getFirstname(),
            $customer->getLastname(),
            $address->getData('street'),
            $address->getData('postcode'),
            $address->getData('city')
        );
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        //var_dump($fields); echo "<br>";
    }
}
```